# Getting Code Contracts to work in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, code-contracts

I have the following code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(SqrtRoot(0));
        Console.WriteLine(SqrtRoot(10));
        Console.WriteLine(SqrtRoot(-10));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static int SqrtRoot(int i)
    {
        Contract.Requires(i >= 0);
        return (int)Math.Sqrt(i);
    }
}
```

I am running it in debug mode, and it should fire some kind of error in the last line

```
Console.WriteLine(SqrtRoot(-10));
```

altough, for some reason, it doesn't. It seems to ignore the Contract.Requires() call. Should I set up something when trying to use Code Contracts?

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 RC.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have that tab either but I found a workaround:

```
Contract.Requires<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(i >= 0);
```

Probably the code contracts package must be installed but the download link is not working. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992.aspx

Comment: That will fire up an error if for values of i = 0, i = 10 and i = -10. I don't get it.

Comment: I've just tried that with Contract.Requires<Exception>(i >= 0); and now the live is not greyed out. Maybe you have to give the exception type as Victor suggests.

Comment: Hm... You're right. Something is not going well there... Even though the default behavior of contracts is to throw an error and display a window.

Comment: I had to install Code Contracts from their site. Now it works as expected with Contract.Requires().

Answer (score 5):

You need to install the Visual Studio integration. While the CodeContracts library itself is part of .NET 4, your code needs to be rewritten by the Code Contracts rewriter (`ccrewrite`) to actually use the library properly.

Download the installer from the [DevLabs site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to enable runtime contract checking in the project settings (there should be a "Code Contracts" pane...)

See the [user documentation](http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/2/7/C2715F76-F56C-4D37-9231-EF8076B7EC13/userdoc.pdf) (section 6) for further information.

Comment: I had thought of that, but I can't find it anywhere on the project's options.